# How to get data from another column in another table to use a a column on another page

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the data from table `PROJECTS` column `Project_id` and use it in another table `Work` which also has a `PROJECT_ID`. What SQL code would I use because I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT -- whatever
FROM 
    Work
     INNER JOIN 
    Projects ON 
        Work.PROJECT_ID = Projects.Project_id
```

EDIT: view syntax ... add in whatever columns you need.

```
CREATE VIEW vwWorkProjects 
AS

SELECT Work.Work_ID, Work.WorkColumn, Projects.Project_ID, Projects.ProjectColumn 
FROM 
    Work
     INNER JOIN 
    Projects ON 
        Work.PROJECT_ID = Projects.Project_id
```

Comment: How would i fix it then

Comment: Add in the columns you want, using the table's alias to identify where each column is coming from, like in the example I just edited.

Comment: how would i call that view aftwards like in a tabular report

Comment: this is the final view CREATE VIEW vwWorkProjects 
AS

SELECT Work.TASK_ID, Work.TASK_DESCRIPTION,  Work.ASSIGNEE,Work.DATE_STARTED,Work.DATE_COMPLETED, Projects.Project_ID, Projects.project
FROM 
    Work
     INNER JOIN 
    Projects ON 
        Work.PROJECT_ID = Projects.Project_id

Comment: ok but how will view this view can i use a select statment or what

Comment: Yes - you can say `SELECT TASK_ID, TASK_DESCRIPTION ... FROM vwWorkProjects`.  You could have even skipped the view and just run the `SELECT Work.TASK_ID, Work.TASK_DESCRIPTION ... FROM Work INNER JOIN Projects ...` statement.

Comment: when i added this view to a tabular form it gave me failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table how do i fix this

Comment: First off, I'm not sure you even really need this as a view... you could just put the `SELECT` statement in your report.  If you do want to keep the view, try Googling the error and let me know if you find anything that applies to your view.

Comment: ok but there are two doffrent tables that need to be joind at the columns so i need to use a view right?

Comment: No ... AFAIK, you can just use the SELECT statement.  I'm not very familiar with your version of Oracle, so I could be wrong ... but try it with just the SELECT.

Comment: @a higgins i think i found the problem, i need to make the row id the same so ill take if from work and use it in projects do you know how i would do this